# Trapping PHP script's normal and abnormal termination

Tags: php, event-handling, shutdown

I have a PHP script that sometimes runs out of memory (the process runs out that it) and terminates abnormally. I want to know if there are any features in PHP that allows me to run a "cleanup" operation when the script terminates. I tried "shutdown handlers" but they do not seem to get called.

Is there anything like "signal handlers" or "shutdown callbacks" that I can use? I want to call a function that does some stuff when the script exits (normally or abnormally).

Comment: Is this command-line PHP or run as part of a web App? Is the PHP code in a framework or library of any kind?

Comment: Have you considered an entry in a database (not sure how often this script runs) that says it has started and is deleted at the end of the script? You could very easily view any and all scripts that failed to complete just by looking at the rows int he table?

Comment: This might help - http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php

Answer (score 0):

There is no cleanup feature within PHP that works like you're hoping. What you can/should do is take a look at your code to see how best to optimize in order to complete the operation you need without running out of memory.

PHP has a function built in that lets you get the current amount of memory allocated to PHP called [memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php). With this you can check how much memory PHP is currently using and compare it to the amount of memory allocated within your `php.ini` file. When you come close to this you can back off or pick up in another thread where this one left off.

Here are some things you can do to tweak PHP and also possibly save some memory, some of which you probably already know but is what I would look if I had the same issue:

- increase the amount of memory within the `php.ini` file if you can, or try to use [ini_set](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) to increase the memory size for PHP. if you raise the amount of memory this may be a temporary solve for the problem
- make use of the [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function as this will deallocate/remove variables and restore some memory used by PHP
- reuse variables whenever possible, this includes encapsulating code within reusable methods/functions as well as making good use of for/foreach/for..in loops
- try not to store large data (text or binary) in memory for extended periods
- write a service to offload memory or processor intensive operations so your main code doesn't timeout executing
- employ queuing so that you're not bound to one thread or by a timeout for the script in order to process everything you need. Perhaps [rabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or another package would work for you

PHP should be able to handle a lot of data and a lot of transformations, but anything you can do to gain efficiencies will just help it along its way.

Hope this helps, 
liam-